# Windows Phone 7 emulator set to 7.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

Microsoft claims that the WP7 emulator supports both 7.0 and 7.1(7.5) builds http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563(v=vs.92).aspx
I am developing a web app for this device and need to see the browser in its 7.0 state ( user agent IEMobile/7 ) and its 7.1 state ( user agent IEMobile/9 ). The emulator is set to 7.1 be default, and I cannot figure out how to get it to display to 7.0 browser. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?